# Defer loading of HTML widget with script tag

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed, deferred-loading

I have a call-to-action widget that I'd like to display above the fold for mobile devices. However, Google PageSpeed is penalizing me for loading a widget before the main content loads. I tried embedding the widget in a `script` tag with a `defer` attribute, but now the widget is not loading at all.

With this code, I got a Google PageSpeed score of 99 for mobile, but the widget does not load.

```
<?php if(is_mobile()) : ?>
  <script  type="text/html" defer>
    <div class="widget">Call Now</div>
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

With this code, the widget does load in mobile devices, but my Google Page Speed score falls to 93.

```
<?php if(is_mobile()) : ?>
    <div class="widget">Call Now</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the full HTML widget, along with the fix suggested by @randy-casburn. The widget does not load with this code either.

```
<?php if(is_mobile()) : ?>
  <script defer>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<div id="mobile-cta" class="widget-wrapper widget_text"><div class="widget-title"><h3>Call or Email Now</h3></div><div class="textwidget"><span class="desktop-number">During office hours: 999.999.9999<br /></span><span class="mobile-number">During office hours: <a href="tel:9999999999" onClick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/widgetTel']);">999.999.9999</a><br /></span>After hours:  <a href="mailto:email@email.com" onClick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/widgetEmail']);">email@email.com</a><br /></div></div>';}</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Edit: added example of penalized code.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] of the working example that Google punished you for?

Comment: You can not use a script element to embed any arbitrary content in a directly visible manner. If you use it this way, then you have to grab the content of that script element afterwards, and embed it into the actual document outside of the script element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<div class="widget">Call Now</div>';
});
```

This will allow the DOM to be constructed first and then add your div and that should do the trick.

Comment: I changed the script type to "application/javascript" and then placed the suggested code inside the script tag, but the widget is still not loading. The HTML widget includes onClick events, if that matters.

Comment: Remove the type attribute. It is no longer necessary in modern browsers. (the correct type is `text/javascript`).

Comment: I've removed the type attribute but the widget is still not loading. I've added the full HTML widget to the original question, in case I am implementing your suggestion incorrectly.

Comment: Are you using a JS library to initialize this widget in some way, or is this a CSS only thing? If JS is required to make this thing work, that JS must run after the widget is added to the page.

Comment: I'm referencing the ga.js legacy JS library from Google, although I didn't think the library would be required at the time the widget first loads

Comment: I decided to use a WordPress plugin instead of writing custom code, but I did find your answer helpful

Comment: You're missing the closing ");"